# Being Motzi someone with Tefilas Haderech

Tags: halacha, tefilla, motzi-yedei-chovato, tefilat-haderech

I was always under the impression that one person can say Tefilas Haderech and the others can answer Amein and you are Motzi them.

Today I was travelling and the fellow said Tefilas Haderech and when he finished he said he did not have me in mind, since he has heard that Tefilas Haderech is a Tefila one has to say it alone and can not be Motzi others. He did not know the source, and I was wondering who is the source of this ruling and what are the dissenting opinions?

Answer (score 4):

It is based on the difference between a tefillah and a bracha. The difference is that one can be yotzi when someone recites a bracha (as with hamotzi) but must recite a tefila personally (as with shmona esrai) unless with a minyan and in extraordinary circumstances (which is the basis of *chazaras Hashatz*)

We see at [Kollel Shaarei Horaah](http://shaareihoraah.org/wordpress/?p=577)

> HaRav Shmuel Kaminetzky shlita ruled that Tefilas HaDerech is a Tefila
>   and not merely a Bracha. Consequently, he advised the Bochrim in
>   Yeshiva that each must recite it himself, and not rely on a single
>   individual saying it out loud for everyone. Of course, if it is not
>   feasible for the driver to stop and look inside a Siddur and he cannot
>   recite Tefilas HaDerech otherwise, hearing it from another is better
>   than nothing. Especially considering that there are dissenting
>   opinions.

Halachipedia says: [How should it be said](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tefillat_HaDerech#How_it_Should_Be_Said)

> It is preferable that each person say it themselves but the strict law
>   permits one to say it and others to fulfill their obligation by
>   hearing it.
>   [21](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tefillat_HaDerech#cite_note-21)
>
> Piskei Teshuvot 110:3

[dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2012/06/12/tefilas-haderech/) states that one is allowed to hear it from someone else (especially if one is the driver) though it is not preferred.

> If there is another passenger in the car, the passenger should recite tefilas haderech for both of them.
>   If this is not possible, he should insert the text of tefilas haderech into the bracha of Shema Koleinu during the Shemoneh Esrei
>   immediately prior to his trip. (Sh.A. 4, M.B. 21-22, Aruch HaShulchan
>   11, Sefer Ishei Yisrael 50:2, Sefer Tefilah K’Hilchasah chap. 27,
>   footnote 80)
>
> Another option, as we mentioned earlier, is to rely on the opinion that tefilas haderech can be recited even if one is still in the city.
>
> One who is traveling on public transportation, such as a bus or train,
>   should stand in order to recite tefilas haderech, if at all possible,
>   since in this case, standing will not be a cause of delay.
>
> Although one fulfills his obligation of tefilas haderech by hearing it
>   recited by someone else, he should preferably not hear it through a
>   loudspeaker, since the sound heard is not a valid bracha according to
>   some opinions. (Sefer Ishei Yisrael 50, footnote 1, Sefer Halichos
>   Shlomo 22:15)

Comment: Not all tefillot need a Minyan (ie not all tefillot are like the ordinary Shemone Esrei). I don't know how he knows what kind of requirements this one has. Musaf on Rosh HaShana for example I can be Yotzei from the Chazan even without any exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @DoubleAA I do not have a reason, it is just part of the cited reference. I did not copy that quote as it was not directly applicable. Perhaps follow the link.